# Merge sort error - Expression must have a constant value

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void merge(int A[], int p, int q, int r) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int n1 = q - p + 1;
    int n2 = r - q;
    vector<int> L(n1), R(n2);
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = A[p + i - 1];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = A[q + j];
    i = 1;
    j = 1;
    for (k = p ; k < r; k++) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            A[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }else{
            A[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
    }   
}
void merges(int A[], int p, int r) {
    if (p < r) {
        int q = (p + r) / 2;
        merges(A, p, q);
        merges(A, q + 1, r);
        merge(A, p, q, r);
     }
}
void prin(int A[], int n) {
     int j;
     for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d ", A[j]);
     printf("\n");
}
int main(){
    fstream infile;
    infile.open("number.txt");
    if (infile.is_open()) {
        int i;
        int A[20];
        int n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A);
        int p = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            infile >> A[i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (A[j] > p)
                p = A[j];
        }
        merges(A, 0, n);
        prin(A, n); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I got this merge sort program with  int L[n1],R[n2];. Visual studio is giving me "Expression must have a constant value". I'm not sure what to do. I also tried using a vector but got an "Expression: vector subscript out of range" error. The number in the text file are 20 random number from 5 to 900 unsorted. Any pointers on how to put have a non-constant number the array size?

Side note: I set the array int main to 20 because I know the file has 20 numbers. Is there a way to set the array size for a file I don't know how many values will be in it?

Comment: You already figured out the solution to having an array with a variable number of elements - it's `std::vector<>`. You still need to get the size right, though.

Comment: Also, `using namespace std;` is considered harmful: you’re better off writing `std::vector`. A bunch of old code defines other classes called `vector` or especially `string`.

Comment: Use std::stable_sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pre-allocate your vector. You can just keep adding stuff until you are done.

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("TextFile1.txt");
    std::string str;
    std::vector< std::string > strs;
    for( ; std::getline( file, str ); )
        strs.push_back( str );

    std::cout << "the number of entries: " << strs.size( ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the `std::vector` `size()` is what was read from the file.

**Added**: When you start using things from the standard library, [use this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to see what you can do with the likes of std::vector. It explains `push_back` and `size` and all the other members as well as an overview of the functionality.

And as Davislor points out. Get in the habit of not `using namespace` with the standard library. It is not worth it. Google it here on stackoverflow for more info.

Comment: That said, it might be a good idea to `reserve()` as much space as you will need, to avoid potentially needing to move the vector to a different block of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use `n1` or `n2` as array bounds in C++ unless they are constants known at compile-time.  This would work if they were `constexpr` variables.

In C, those expressions would declare variable-length arrays, an optional feature.